# Deriving equipartition the (Sin Itiro Tomonaga ) way

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, statistical-mechanics, integration

In his book on quantum mechanics Tomonaga derives the equipartition law or energy using this integral. I am having several doubts on solving this integral! Is this solvable via this method?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see five lines with integral signs. Which one? And are you really asking if the Boltzmann distribution can be determined?

Comment: the one above the integral where he says , " this can be readily reduced "
and what i am asking is whether this way of working equipartition law is correct or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beginning let's take  $ x= \frac{1}{kT}$, then take
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x\alpha p^2) {\rm d}p
\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \alpha p^2 \exp(-x\alpha p^2) {\rm d}p\end{equation}
Notice that $f=-\frac{{\rm d}g}{{\rm d}x}$. For (1) Take the same expression, but use $p'$ instead of $p$ and multiply to get

\begin{equation} \tag{3}
g(x)^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x\alpha (p^2+p'^2)) {\rm d}p{\rm d}p'
\end{equation}

Above trick is used in error function calculation.  The next step is to convert them to cylindrical coordinates ($r^2=p^2+p'^2$) to get

\begin{equation} \tag{4}
g(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{\alpha x}}\rightarrow f(x)= \frac{g(x)}{2x}
\end{equation}
then this gives $f(x)=\frac{kT}{2} g(x)$